# Is there a change I can make to avoid negative R2 scores in SVR?

Tags: python, regression, svm

I'm using Support Vector Regression to predict an Extroversion Score based on the rest of the features in the dataset. However, the R2 scores I keep generating are negative.

I tried using different kernels for the SVR function and using only some of the features in the dataset to predict the Score but the R2 scores remain negative.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Training Dataset.csv')

X = df.iloc[:, 1:11]
y = df.iloc[:, 0]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

best_svr = SVR()
r2score = cross_val_score(best_svr, X, y, cv=5)

print(np.mean(r2score))
```

There are no error messages, but the R2 scores remain negative. I'm not sure if it is because it is a poor model or if I can alter my code to correct this. My dataset is about 14000 x 12 and the scores I want to predict range from -0.3 to 0.5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you fit a simple data set such as "x = [1.0, 2.0. 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0];y = [11.1, 12.2, 13.3, 14.4, 15.5, 16.6, 17.7, 18.8, 19.9]" does this still happen?